# How React search (filter) all field in array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My search function use filter a field in array.
I try other ways but not success.
May I use a single line of code to search (filter) all field in array?

Search Code as following:
(if I have many fields in the array. ex: "title", "date", "id", "name")

```
filterList = (e) => {
    let { value } = e.target
    this.setState({ value }, () => {

        var updatedList = this.state.issues;
        updatedList = updatedList.filter((item) => {
            return item.title.toLowerCase().search(this.state.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
        });
        this.setState({ issues: updatedList });
    });
  }
```

I finally found that the search function should remove some function in Pagination as below code that I comment out:

```
setPage(page) {
        var { items, pageSize } = this.props;
        var pager = this.state.pager;

        //if (page < 1 || page > pager.totalPages) {
        //  return;
        //}

        pager = this.getPager(items.length, page, pageSize);
        var pageOfItems = items.slice(pager.startIndex, pager.endIndex + 1);
        this.setState({ pager: pager });
        this.props.onChangePage(pageOfItems);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `some` method in combination with `Object.Keys` for **filtering** all the fields.

```
var searchValue = this.state.value.toLowerCase();
updatedList = updatedList.filter((item) => {
    return Object.keys(item).some(key => item[key].toString().search(searchValue) !== -1);
});
```

Comment: Hi Mihai, it's work!! Anyway I'm also interest in the way to render by h1b9b.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys` to get an array of the object keys. You should also use setState only ones if you want to avoid unnecessary rerenders

```
filterList = (e) => {
    let { value } = e.target
    this.setState((previousState) => {
        var updatedList = previousState.issues;
        updatedList = updatedList.filter(
          (item) => Object.keys(item).some(key => item[key].search(value) !== -1)    
        );
        return {
          value,
          issues: updatedList
        }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hi h1b9b, Thanks for your response, could you please fix the parentheses?

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut You need to close the filter function

Answer (score 0):

More powerful search by filter function to prevent "null" value using validation.

```
const searchQuery = products.filter((query) => {
  return Object.keys(query).some(key => 
    (typeof query[key] === 'string' && query[key].includes(searchValue))
    || (typeof query[key] === 'number') && query[key] === Number(searchValue))
})
```